# Guard not sending gntp notifications to growl

Tags: ruby, guard, minitest, growl

I am using guard with minitest, and everything works great except growl notifications don't work.

#### Gemfile

```
gem 'growl'
gem 'guard'
gem 'guard-minitest'
gem 'json'
gem 'minitest'
gem 'rack-test'
gem 'ruby_gntp'
gem 'sinatra'
```

#### Guardfile

```
guard :minitest do
  watch(%r{^spec/(.*)_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^spec/test_helper.rb$})
  watch('beacons_app.rb') { "spec/beacons_app_spec.rb" }
end

notification :gntp
```

(NOTE: I have tried putting the "notification" line at the top of the file as well)

If I run `bundle exec guard notifiers` gntp shows as available:

```
  +-------------------+-----------+------+--------+-------------+
  | Name              | Available | Used | Option | Value       |
  +-------------------+-----------+------+--------+-------------+
  | gntp              | ✔         | ✔    | title  | "Notiffany" |
  |                   |           |      | sticky | false       |
  +-------------------+-----------+------+--------+-------------+
  | growl             | ✘         | ✘    |        |             |
  +-------------------+-----------+------+--------+-------------+
  | terminal_notifier | ✘         | ✘    |        |             |
  +-------------------+-----------+------+--------+-------------+
  | libnotify         | ✘         | ✘    |        |             |
  +-------------------+-----------+------+--------+-------------+
  | notifysend        | ✘         | ✘    |        |             |
  +-------------------+-----------+------+--------+-------------+
  | notifu            | ✘         | ✘    |        |             |
  +-------------------+-----------+------+--------+-------------+
  | emacs             | ✘         | ✘    |        |             |
  +-------------------+-----------+------+--------+-------------+
  | tmux              | ✘         | ✘    |        |             |
  +-------------------+-----------+------+--------+-------------+
  | terminal_title    | ✔         | ✔    | title  | "Notiffany" |
  +-------------------+-----------+------+--------+-------------+
  | file              | ✘         | ✘    |        |             |
  +-------------------+-----------+------+--------+-------------+
```

Growl is running and working (I can send to it successfully using `growlnotify` at the command line).

And when I run `bundle exec guard`, my tests run fine, and file changes trigger the tests to rerun in the terminal, as expected.  But no growl notifications.

How can I make them work?

## UPDATE

This was caused by a bug in guard-minitest, and it has now been fixed: https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest/commit/35ba44c2df7d25b8c3631be2571d3f1411e64185

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hmmm, my first guess would be that guard is not enabled in your growl settings:

have you checked your growl preferences?

[image: growl preferences]

I would also check http://www.rubydoc.info/github/guard/guard/Guard/Notifier/Growl
to ensure you have correct config options. if that doesn't work, open an issue at https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest/issues

**Update: looks like this was a bug in guard-minitest** https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest/issues/126

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This looks promising, since Guard is indeed not listed in my Growl application prefs.  However, I don't see how to add it.  My screen is different from yours (v2.1.3) and I have a "Get Applications" button rather than a "Configure."  It links [here](http://www.growl.info/applications.php), and Guard is not among the apps listed.

Comment: im running growl 1.3.3, looks like i need to upgrade :)

Comment: It looks like there is no way to manually add guard to the list of applications in growl: http://growl.info/documentation/faq.php#how-do-I-add-app-X.  I wonder why it failed to register itself with growl, or if there is any way I can force it to.

Comment: also, fwiw, I'm running Guard version 2.11.1 on ruby 2.1.3

Comment: i will try to uninstall guard and see if that removes it from list, then reinstall, one sec

Comment: weird, even uninstalling guard from system didnt remove it from list - i checked out http://growl.info/documentation/faq.php, looks like growl has to register itself as an app on install. what happens if you do complete reinstall of guard?

Comment: just a thought, something else you could try: `gem open guard-minitest` and view this file https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest/blob/master/lib/guard/minitest/notifier.rb#L26, set some breakpoints and take it from there

Comment: `gem uninstall guard` followed by `gem install guard` had no effect -- it's still not listed in growl....

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was a bug in guard-minitest, and it's now bee fixed.  If you update your answer, I'll mark it as accepted.